# Replace all elements in string after a specified position

Tags: regex, r, string

I would like to replace all elements in a string after a specified position that varies among strings.  Ideally the solution would use `regex` in base `R`.

Here is a worked example and the desired result:

```
my.last.position <- c(5, 7, 3, NA, 10)

my.data <- read.table(text='
                         my.string
                         .1.222.2.2
                         ..1..1..2.
                         1.1.2.2...
                         .222.232..
                         ..1..1...1
', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
my.data

desired.result <- read.table(text='
                         my.string
                         .1.22.....
                         ..1..1....
                         1.1.......
                         .222.232..
                         ..1..1...1
', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
desired.result
```

The vector `my.last.position` specifies the last position to retain in each string.  The `data.frame` `desired.result` contains the desired result.

Thanks for any advice.  Sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Unlike your other question which is a unitary 1 to 1 relationship that is a valid floating global replace, this isn't the same. This requires counting and regex can't do counting. It might be doable in a recursive replacement, but it can't be a global one. For example, where the regex is constructed for each line find `^(.{N}.*?)2` replace `$1` using  it in a while ( gsub() ). loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully someone can come up with a more elegant solution than this, but here goes:

```
mapply(
    function(s,i) paste(collapse='',if (is.na(i)) s else c(s[seq_len(i)],rep('.',length(s)-i))),
    strsplit(my.data$my.string,''),
    my.last.position
);
## [1] ".1.22....." "..1..1...." "1.1......." ".222.232.." "..1..1...1"
```

Comment: That is really neat.

Comment: If I want to replace all elements before a specified position I can do it by modifying your function line: `function(s,i) paste(collapse = '', if (is.na(i)) s else c(rep('.', i-1),  s[i:length(s)]  )),`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method. Not sure that it is any more elegant:

```
# as in the example output, any NAs are treated as do not mess with this
# vector element
my.last.position.NoNA <- ifelse(is.na(my.last.position),
                                nchar(my.data$my.string), my.last.position)

# perform the replacement
paste0(substr(my.data$my.string, 1, my.last.position.NoNA), 
  sapply(1:nrow(my.data), function(i) paste0(rep(".", 
                length=(nchar(my.data$my.string[i])-my.last.position[i])),
                collapse="")))
```